# Error: Cannot find module './is-buffer'

Tags: node.js, module

I haven't found any posts that have an answer for this one. It appears to be a sourcing issue, but no matter what I try I can't seem to source it properly. I get the following error when trying to launch my application.

is-buffer is installed. I see it in my node-modules directory.

```
C:\MY-APP\dataService>node dataAPI.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module './is-buffer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MY-APP\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\so
ket.io-adapter\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I tried setting this in my binary file as well as my package.json. I'm able to change it in my binary file, but no matter what I'm not able to find the correct src dir.

I also tried **npm install is-buffer -g** to no avail. Any advice?

---

### Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I was able to update the source to

```
 var isBuf = require('C:\VF_PDO_APP\node_modules\is-buffer');
```

So now it seems to be going to the right place I think. Now however, I'm getting **Unexpected token ILLEGAL**.

```
C:\MY-APP\dataService>node dataAPI.js
C:\MY-APP\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\node_modules\socket.io-parser\binary.js:10
socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\node_modules\socket.io-parser
   ^^^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
 at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
 at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
 at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
 at require (module.js:384:17)
 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MY-APP\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\soc
 ket.io-adapter\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:10:14)
 at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: One of your files are trying find that folder. It seems to be socket-io-parser, try to install it again. Probably there were was an error during the installation of that module.

Comment: Have you tried to update/reinstall socket.io package? When you installed it in the first time there was no errors?
Respond me here in the comments so I can get the notification.

Comment: I tried updating and reinstalling socket.io now I'm getting this error.

C:\MY-APP\dataService>node dataAPI.js
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Wed Aug 19 2015 08:50:58 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time): Node server started o
n 127.0.0.1:3000 ...

Answer (score 1):

You first must install all your project dependencies, do it on the root folder of your project:
`npm install`

For your problem with socket.io try to:
`npm install socket.io --save`

For the bson problem:
`npm install bson --save`
(for this one probably you will need to install python and c++)

Comment: Tried all the above and still getting the bson error.

Comment: Update your post with a stack trace of the error formated.

Comment: what is the "bson" problem? is it the is-buffer issue?  I have that in trying to browserify from grunt...